# How do I prove that the eigenvalue of isometry is $ -1$ or $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the eigenvalue of isometry is either $1$ or $-1$, but can't figure out how to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you find this question? What are your thoughts on the question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is true only in a real inner product space. It is obviously false otherwise. Consider $x\mapsto \sqrt{-1}\,x$ for instance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $A$ is an isometry, then $\langle Av, Av \rangle = \langle v,v \rangle, \ \forall v$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $Av = \lambda v$, for some $v$. What can you conclude by putting together both definitions?

Answer (score 2):

An [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) should preserves norm of a vactor. So, if you are working on a real inner product space, say $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, for instance. Let $A:H\to H$ being an isometry.

Let u∈H being a non null eigenvector, associated to an eigenvalue λ. Then you should have $\langle u,u\rangle=\langle Au,Au\rangle=\langle \lambda u,\lambda u\rangle=|\lambda|^2\langle u,u\rangle$.

You can find more about isometry searching for "\( \langle u,u\rangle=\langle Au,Au\rangle\)   isometry" on SearchOnMath.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is not true. An example is given below.

An isometry $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^p$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$ satisfies $\| f(x) - f(b) \| = \| a - b \|$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^p$. So, [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) are examples of isometric maps on $\mathbb{R}^p$. Consider the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
\begin{align}
R(\theta)
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Its [characteristic equation is](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph116A/Rotation2.pdf) $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda \cos \theta + 1 = 0$, whose roots are $e^{\pm i \theta}$. The roots are not real unless $\theta = 0, \pi$.

Comment: This does not invalidate the assertion in the question. A rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no eigenvectors, except for the two cases you mentioned.

Comment: The assertion should read: If $T$ is an isometry and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: @Ihf in that case the other answers address the question. I showed that the assertion in the question as it stands is not true, and I did everything by definition. Roots of the characteristic equation _are_ the eigenvalues, and they can be complex perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

If $Q$ is an isometry, it preserves the length of a vector $x$. That is, $\|Qx\|=\|x\|$. Intuitively it means that it does not *stretch* the vector $x$. For this $Qx= \lambda x$ for some $\lambda$ which does not change its length. This is possible only if $\lambda=-1, +1$. In that case indeed:

$$\|Qx\|= \|\lambda x\|= |\lambda|\|x\|=\|x\|$$